# How do I pass a double pointer from a third function to a fourth in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I need to pass a double pointer from one function to a second to a third. For instance:

```
char *text = "some text";
func2(&text);

void func2(char **text){
  func3(&text);
}

void func3(char **text) ...
```

Is this valid? Is there a better way to ensure that all these functions can edit this variable (without it being global)?

Comment: Show an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you wanting all these functions to edit the pointer (to make it point somewhere else), or are you wanting all these functions to be able to edit the data(text) which the pointer points to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to use `&text` in `func2()`. `text` is already a pointer to the original variable, you can just pass it as it is.

You also need to specify the type that the pointer points to in the function signatures.

```
void func2(char **text){
  func3(text);
}
void func3(char **text) ...
```